# Unable to connect Django docker image to GCP instance using GCloud Proxy

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose

I am using cloud_proxy to connect to google cloud postgres instance. I followed the steps in GCP website https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-admin-proxy. When I run it locally using python manage.py runserver with host for db as 127.0.0.1 and port as 5432, the program is working fine.

If I try to dockerize the application and run the program, I am facing the error

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Docker file

services:
web:
build: .
command: python manage.py runserver

```
volumes:
  - .:/code
ports:
  - 8000:8000
```

So I tried to dockerize the application using the stack overflow answer [Is there a way to access google cloud SQL via proxy inside docker container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836831/is-there-a-way-to-access-google-cloud-sql-via-proxy-inside-docker-container) modified the host in settings.py file too.

Now facing the error
gcloud is not in the path and -instances and -projects are empty

services:

web:

```
build: .
command: python manage.py runserver
depends_on:
  - cloud-sql-proxy
volumes:
  - .:/code
ports:
  - 8000:8000
env_file:
  - ./.env.dev
```

cloud-sql-proxy:

```
image: gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16

command: /cloud_sql_proxy --dir=/cloudsql instances=abc:us-central1:def=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json

ports:
  - 5432:5432

volumes:
  - credentials.json:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json

restart: always
```

Could you please help me with this issue. My requirement is to create a docker image with Django application so that it can be deployed to GCP.

Comment: If you find my answer useful, please consider upvoting/accepting it, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I think You are missing `-` It should be

```
command: /cloud_sql_proxy --dir=/cloudsql -instances=abc:us-central1:def=tcp:0.0.0.0:5432 -credential_file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to follow the next documentation:

[Connecting psql client using the Cloud SQL Proxy docker Image](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/connect-docker)

This page describes how to connect a psql client to your Cloud SQL instance, from a client machine running Linux or Compute Engine Linux instance, using the Cloud SQL Proxy Docker image, I think this guide could meet  your needs.

This guide mentions the way to start the proxy at point 9.
Unix sockets:

```
docker run -d -v /cloudsql:/cloudsql \
  -v <PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>:/config \
  gcr.io/cloudsql-docker/gce-proxy:1.16 /cloud_sql_proxy -dir=/cloudsql \
  -instances=<INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME> -credential_file=/config
```

If you are using the credentials provided by your Compute Engine instance, do not include the `credential_file` parameter and the `-v <PATH_TO_KEY_FILE>:/config` line.
If you are using a container optimized image, use a writeable directory in place of `/cloudsql`, for example:

```
-v /mnt/stateful_partition/cloudsql:/cloudsql
```

Additionally if you want to know more about Cloud SQL Proxy parameters and flags I recommend to take a look at this [page](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/sql-proxy#flags)

I hope this information would be useful to you