# Troubleshooting Google Cloud SQL connection through Auth Proxy in Docker

Tags: docker, proxy, google-cloud-sql

I've set up a `docker-compose.yml` to a run node-based API application and [Google's Cloud SQL Auth Proxy](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy?tab=readme-ov-file) for the API to connect to my Cloud SQL instance. Both applications start, but the I'm getting the error below in my API container:

```
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:3307 at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect
```

even though the terminal in my proxy container reads:

```
Authorizing with the credentials file at "/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json"
[myproject:myregion:myinstance] Listening on 127.0.0.1:3307
The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!
```

docker-compose.yml ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45836831/is-there-a-way-to-access-google-cloud-sql-via-proxy-inside-docker-container))

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.2
    # also tried --address 0.0.0.0
    command: myproject:myregion:myinstance --credentials-file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json --address 127.0.0.1 --port=3307
    ports:
      - 127.0.0.1:3307:3307
    volumes:
      - ./cloud-sql.credentials.json:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
    restart: always

  web-api:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/web-api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    depends_on:
      - proxy
```

**Authentication**

**Mounting** - As you can see I'm mounting `credentials.json` which is a key file for my service account with `Cloud SQL Client` privileges. I've confirmed that the file is mounted properly by looking at the container files in Docker desktop.

**Reading** - I also confirmed that the proxy is reading the key file. To do so, I deleted the `type` property in the key file and I get the error `config error: missing 'type' field in credentials`

**IAM Permissions** - I was able to run the proxy locally and connect successfully with a desktop client using this key file, so the key file has the [correct permissions](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sql-proxy?tab=readme-ov-file#credentials) (Cloud SQL Client).

But this is weird...

I deleted a character from the service account email to test that the key file authentication would fail. Locally I get the error `Invalid grant: account not found`, but in my docker container, the proxy runs without error.

I don't know what to make of this, or how to troubleshoot it. Have I configured something incorrectly? How is the proxy starting with a bad key file when I know the proxy is reading it properly?

Comment: In Docker, the special loopback IPv4 address 127.0.0.1 almost always means "the current container".  See for example [Networking in Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/) in the Docker documentation for details on connecting to other containers.

Comment: (...and you will need the `--address 0.0.0.0`; the `--address 127.0.0.1` setting I'm guessing will make the proxy container inaccessible from other containers or from the host.)

Comment: You are running two containers via Docker Compose. One container needs to open a connection to the other container. You are not using the built-in network features to support container -> container networking. Please see this [link](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/)

Comment: The error suggests your app can't reach the Proxy. Otherwise your Proxy setup looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to reference your Proxy container using [links](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#link-containers).

Try this (adapting as needed):

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  proxy:
    # binding to 0.0.0.0 is important
    image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.2
    command: myproject:myregion:myinstance --credentials-file=/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json --address 0.0.0.0 --port=3307
    volumes:
    - ./cloud-sql.credentials.json:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json

  psql:
    image: postgres
    # using "proxy" as the hostname
    command: psql "host=proxy port=3307 user=postgres dbname=postgres password=mycoolpassword" -c "select now()"
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    links:
    - "proxy"
```

Comment: I'm not using postgres, but this proxy part worked. I have since switched from a TCP connection to a Unix socket so I'll add an answer for reference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for a unix socket connection:

```yaml
version: '3.8'

services:
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    image: gcr.io/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy:2.8.2
    command: myproject:myregion:myinstance --unix-socket /tmp --credentials-file /secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
    volumes:
      - ./cloud-sql.credentials.json:/secrets/cloudsql/credentials.json
      - socket:/tmp
    restart: always

  web-api:
    container_name: web-api
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./apps/web-api/Dockerfile
    ports:
      - 3333:3333
    volumes:
      - socket:/tmp
    depends_on:
      - proxy
    env_file:
      - .env
    restart: always

volumes:
  socket:
```